# Must a freelancer keep API Client IDs active for former employers?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I'm a newb with Google OAuth and am trying to understand the different business/application models and which API credential types go with my particular situation.

I am creating a Chrome extension for someone for their own private use which accesses their Google Sheets docs using their personal Sheets account.  So, I will not own the code or extension once I deliver it to them and end the contract.  So, I do not want to have to maintain any authorization/API ID's or credentials after I deliver the extension and its source code.  But, obviously, the extension must continue to work for them indefinitely.

The only way I can see how to accomplish this is to instruct the employer (who has no developer or development skills) on how to create the OAuth Client ID with their own Google API developer console.  Then, they can enter the client ID and other codes if necessary into the extension config screen so the extension can use this information for authorizing API calls.  This seems like a huge hassle for someone who just wants to buy an extension to do something simple.

Am I missing something?  Is there an easier way?

P.S.  I know this question doesn't follow the proper format for SO, but this is the only place Google has provided for asking API OAuth 2.0 questions.

Comment: Is this another dumb question?  Google needs a developer forum.

Comment: I think your question is valid, but may be a better fit for another SE site: [programmers.se]. It's not so much a question about implementation as it is about development practices.